# why  onItemSelected() not return "null" value when nothing selected from spinner

Tags: android

in my app i have a spinner and a button below it when i run the program suppose this page is open which contains spinner and a button ,when i dont select any item from spineer it takes first values of spinner by default i want if nothing is selected it contains null value ..... how to do this??? thankss a lot  my code is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI Saurabh,

I would suggest you to give your first spinner value as "--Select--" or some message. And try to validate in your code, by checking return value of the spinner which should not be the first manual value that you given into the spinner.

You can refer this page
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: Kanaga  hi..but dear i filled the value in spinner by array list and array list data comes from after sax xml parsing ...then how to enter my own value in that spinner...

Answer (score 0):

the parameter "position" records your selected item.so you can use this parameter.